# Muxing from Audio and Video files with FFmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am learning how to create MP4 video from [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html) example.The problem is that the example demonstrates audio encoding from some dummy source data generated on the fly.I need to encode audio from a file.I have checked many examples and most of them show the same or just a separate audio encoding.
In my trial and error process I am using the same AVFormatContext for both audio and video frames.I am not sure if it's right thing to do, or should I rather have 2 separate contexts?So far I got Video encoding ok but audio stream fails as AVPacket can't locate correct audio stream index.
Here is how I setup audio stream:

```
  void open_audio(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec **codec, AVStream **st ,enum AVCodecID codec_id){

    //    AVCodecContext *c;
    int ret;
    //    c = st->codec;

    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",avcodec_get_name(codec_id));

    }
    /* open it */



    if(avformat_open_input(&oc,_audioInName.c_str(),NULL,NULL) !=0){

        Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Error opening audio file");

    }


    AVStream* audioStream = NULL;

    // Find the audio stream (some container files can have multiple streams in them)

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < oc->nb_streams; ++i)

    {

        if (oc->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)

        {

            audioStream = oc->streams[i];

            break;

        }

    }

    if (audioStream == NULL)
    {
        Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Could not find any audio stream in the file");

    }
    *st =audioStream;

    AVCodecContext *c  = audioStream->codec;
    c->codec = *codec;//avcodec_find_decoder(c->codec_id);
    audioStream->id = 1;
    c->sample_fmt  = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
    c->bit_rate    = 64000;
    c->sample_rate = 44100;
    c->channels    = 1;

    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER){
        c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    }

    if (c->codec == NULL)
    {
        Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Couldn't find a proper decoder");

    }

    ret = avcodec_open2(c, *codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {

        Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Could not open audio codec\n");

    }

}
```

Here "oc" is the same context used to initialize video stream as well.

Then I am trying to write audio frame like this:

```
  void write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st){
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 }; // data and size must be 0;
    AVFrame *frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    int got_packet, ret;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    c = st->codec;
    /////
    //  get_audio_frame(samples, audio_input_frame_size, c->channels);

    ////Read the packet:
    while(av_read_frame(oc,&pkt) == 0 ){

        if(pkt.stream_index ==st->index){

        // Try to decode the packet into a frame
        int frameFinished = 0;
        avcodec_decode_audio4(c, frame, &frameFinished, &pkt);

        // Some frames rely on multiple packets, so we have to make sure the frame is finished before
        // we can use it
        if (frameFinished){
            assert(frameFinished);
            ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Error encoding audio frame\n");

            }
            if (!got_packet){
                printf("failed to aquire packet");
            }
            pkt.stream_index = st->index;
            /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
            if (ret != 0) {

                Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Error while writing audio frame.");
            }

          }
        }

       }
    }
    av_free_packet(&pkt);
    avcodec_free_frame(&frame);
}
```

The thing is I never pass this statement: "if(pkt.stream_index ==st->index)".Packet stream index is never equal to the audio stream index.Anyone can point out where I am wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I did managed to open input audio stream for encoding but I can't encode audio and video streams into single output.From what I see PTS and DTS are probably the source of the problem.Currently I calculate pts based on muxing.c example but it doesn't work for audio at all.

Here is how I use it :

```
   while(frame_count < _streamDurationNBFrames-1){

        uint8_t *frameToWrite =_frames.front();


        // Compute current audio and video time. ///

        if (audio_st){
            audio_pts = (double)audioIn_st->pts.val * audioIn_st->time_base.num / audioIn_st->time_base.den;
        }
        else{

            audio_pts = 0.0;
        }
        if (video_st){

            video_pts = (double)video_st->pts.val * video_st->time_base.num /   video_st->time_base.den;

        }else{
            video_pts = 0.0;
        }


        if ((!audio_st || audio_pts >= _streamDuration) && (!video_st || video_pts >= _streamDuration)){

            break;

        }


        if (audio_st && audio_pts < video_pts) {
            av_read_frame(informat, &pkt);//read audio from input stream
             Msg::PrintMsg("Encode audio here...");

          //==================   AUDIO ENCODE HERE   


           outpkt.data = pkt.data;
           outpkt.size = pkt.size;
           outpkt.stream_index = pkt.stream_index;
           outpkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
           outpkt.pts = pkt.pts;
           outpkt.dts =pkt.dts;
           if(av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &outpkt) < 0)
           {
            Msg::PrintErrorMsg("Fail Audio Write ");
           }
           else
           {
               audio_st->codec->frame_number++;
           }
           av_free_packet(&outpkt);
           av_free_packet(&pkt);



         }else{
          //==================   VIDEO  ENCODE HERE   

            write_video_frame(oc, video_st,frameToWrite);

            frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base);
         }

        ///at last delete this frame:
        _frames.pop();
        delete frameToWrite; ///deallocate the written frame!
    }
```

Somehow ,once I am in the audio encoding loop the audio_pts never reaches the video_pts and is always zero:

```
audio_pts = (double)audio_st->pts.val * audio_st->time_base.num / audio_st->time_base.den; is always zero because  (double)audio_st->pts.val  returns zero.
```

So basically I am asking the same question again:How to do the muxing when audio comes from external file?

Btw,the answer below doesn't help as it presumes both audio and video streams come from the same file, whereas in my case only audio comes from the external source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make you of the same context there is no need for two separate context.  If you are encoding both video and audio. Then you will first need to create video stream and then audio stream. However if you want to just encode only audio then you will need to create just audio stream. 
if(pkt.stream_index ==st->index) is normally required when you are transcoding i.e when you are change container format. In which can you will be reading frame from a video file and write to another file, so you need to know if the frame is from audio or video stream. 
However if you are getting decoded audio packets then you will need to set proper stream index in audio packet before do av_interleaved_write.

In your code you are not setting pts and dts of audio packets which are required for proper encoding.

Sometime ago I've written a similar program like your, you can look into it for your reference.

```
int VideoClipper::Init(const wxString& filename)
{
    int ret = 0;
    char errbuf[64];

    av_register_all();
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input( &m_informat, filename.mb_str(), 0, 0)) != 0 )
    {
        av_strerror(ret,errbuf,sizeof(errbuf));
        PRINT_VAL("Not able to Open file;; ", errbuf)
        ret = -1;
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        PRINT_MSG("Opened File ")
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(m_informat, 0))< 0 )
    {

        av_strerror(ret,errbuf,sizeof(errbuf));
        PRINT_VAL("Not Able to find stream info:: ", errbuf)
        ret = -1;
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        PRINT_MSG("Got stream Info ")
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<m_informat->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if(m_informat->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {

            PRINT_MSG("Found Video Stream ")
            m_in_vid_strm_idx = i;
            m_in_vid_strm = m_informat->streams[i];
        }

        if(m_informat->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Found Audio Stream ")
            m_in_aud_strm_idx = i;
            m_in_aud_strm = m_informat->streams[i];
        }
    }

    if(m_in_aud_strm_idx == -1 && m_in_vid_strm_idx == -1)
    {
       ret = -1;    
    }

    if(m_informat->duration == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
    {
        if(m_in_vid_strm_idx != -1 && m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx])
        {
            if(m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->duration != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            {
                //m_in_end_time = (m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->duration)/(AV_TIME_BASE);
                m_in_end_time = (m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->duration)/(m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->time_base.den/m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->time_base.num);

            }

        }
        else if(m_in_aud_strm_idx != -1 && m_informat->streams[m_in_aud_strm_idx])
        {
            if(m_informat->streams[m_in_aud_strm_idx]->duration != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
            {
                m_in_end_time = (m_informat->streams[m_in_aud_strm_idx]->duration)/(AV_TIME_BASE);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_in_end_time = (m_informat->duration)/(AV_TIME_BASE);
    }

    if(m_in_vid_strm_idx != -1 && m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx])
    {
        if(m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->r_frame_rate.num != AV_NOPTS_VALUE && m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->r_frame_rate.den != 0)
        {
            m_fps =  (m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->r_frame_rate.num)/ (m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->r_frame_rate.den);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_fps = 25;    
    }
    AVOutputFormat *outfmt = NULL;
    std::string outfile = std::string(filename) + "clip_out.avi";
    outfmt = av_guess_format(NULL,outfile.c_str(),NULL);

    if(outfmt == NULL)
    {
        ret = -1;
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        m_outformat = avformat_alloc_context();
        if(m_outformat)
        {
            m_outformat->oformat = outfmt;
            _snprintf(m_outformat->filename, sizeof(m_outformat->filename), "%s", outfile.c_str());    
        }
        else
        {
            ret = -1;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    AVCodec *out_vid_codec,*out_aud_codec;
    out_vid_codec = out_aud_codec = NULL;

    if(outfmt->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE && m_in_vid_strm != NULL)
    {
        out_vid_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(outfmt->video_codec);
        if(NULL == out_vid_codec)
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Could Not Find Vid Encoder")
            ret = -1;
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Found Out Vid Encoder ")
            m_out_vid_strm = avformat_new_stream(m_outformat, out_vid_codec);
            if(NULL == m_out_vid_strm)
            {
                 PRINT_MSG("Failed to Allocate Output Vid Strm ")
                 ret = -1;
                 return ret;
            }
            else
            {
                 PRINT_MSG("Allocated Video Stream ")
                 if(avcodec_copy_context(m_out_vid_strm->codec, m_informat->streams[m_in_vid_strm_idx]->codec) != 0)
                 {
                    PRINT_MSG("Failed to Copy Context ")
                    ret = -1;
                    return ret;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    m_out_vid_strm->sample_aspect_ratio.den = m_out_vid_strm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.den;
                    m_out_vid_strm->sample_aspect_ratio.num = m_in_vid_strm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.num;
                    PRINT_MSG("Copied Context ")
                    m_out_vid_strm->codec->codec_id = m_in_vid_strm->codec->codec_id;
                    m_out_vid_strm->codec->time_base.num = 1;
                    m_out_vid_strm->codec->time_base.den = m_fps*(m_in_vid_strm->codec->ticks_per_frame);         
                    m_out_vid_strm->time_base.num = 1;
                    m_out_vid_strm->time_base.den = 1000;
                    m_out_vid_strm->r_frame_rate.num = m_fps;
                    m_out_vid_strm->r_frame_rate.den = 1;
                    m_out_vid_strm->avg_frame_rate.den = 1;
                    m_out_vid_strm->avg_frame_rate.num = m_fps;
                    m_out_vid_strm->duration = (m_out_end_time - m_out_start_time)*1000;
                 }
               }
            }
      }

    if(outfmt->audio_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE && m_in_aud_strm != NULL)
    {
        out_aud_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(outfmt->audio_codec);
        if(NULL == out_aud_codec)
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Could Not Find Out Aud Encoder ")
            ret = -1;
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Found Out Aud Encoder ")
            m_out_aud_strm = avformat_new_stream(m_outformat, out_aud_codec);
            if(NULL == m_out_aud_strm)
            {
                PRINT_MSG("Failed to Allocate Out Vid Strm ")
                ret = -1;
                return ret;
            }
            else
            {
                if(avcodec_copy_context(m_out_aud_strm->codec, m_informat->streams[m_in_aud_strm_idx]->codec) != 0)
                {
                    PRINT_MSG("Failed to Copy Context ")
                    ret = -1;
                    return ret;
                }
                else
                 {
                    PRINT_MSG("Copied Context ")
                    m_out_aud_strm->codec->codec_id = m_in_aud_strm->codec->codec_id;
                    m_out_aud_strm->codec->codec_tag = 0;
                    m_out_aud_strm->pts = m_in_aud_strm->pts;
                    m_out_aud_strm->duration = m_in_aud_strm->duration;
                    m_out_aud_strm->time_base.num = m_in_aud_strm->time_base.num;
                    m_out_aud_strm->time_base.den = m_in_aud_strm->time_base.den;

                }
            }
         }
      }

      if (!(outfmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) 
      {
        if (avio_open2(&m_outformat->pb, outfile.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE,NULL, NULL) < 0) 
        {
                PRINT_VAL("Could Not Open File ", outfile)
                ret = -1;
                return ret;
        }
      }
        /* Write the stream header, if any. */
      if (avformat_write_header(m_outformat, NULL) < 0) 
      {
            PRINT_VAL("Error Occurred While Writing Header ", outfile)
            ret = -1;
            return ret;
      }
      else
      {
            PRINT_MSG("Written Output header ")
            m_init_done = true;
      }

    return ret;
}

int VideoClipper::GenerateClip(void)
{
    AVPacket pkt, outpkt;
    int aud_pts = 0, vid_pts = 0, aud_dts = 0, vid_dts = 0;
    int last_vid_pts = 0;
    if(m_good_clip)
    {
        SeekFrame();
        while(av_read_frame(m_informat, &pkt) >= 0 && (m_num_frames-- > 0))
        {
            if(pkt.stream_index == m_in_vid_strm_idx)
            {
                PRINT_VAL("ACTUAL VID Pkt PTS ",av_rescale_q(pkt.pts,m_in_vid_strm->time_base, m_in_vid_strm->codec->time_base))
                PRINT_VAL("ACTUAL VID Pkt DTS ", av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, m_in_vid_strm->time_base, m_in_vid_strm->codec->time_base ))
                av_init_packet(&outpkt);
                if(pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                {
                    if(last_vid_pts == vid_pts)
                    {
                        vid_pts++;
                        last_vid_pts = vid_pts;
                    }
                    outpkt.pts = vid_pts;   
                    PRINT_VAL("ReScaled VID Pts ", outpkt.pts)
                }
                else
                {
                    outpkt.pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
                }

                if(pkt.dts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                {
                    outpkt.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    outpkt.dts = vid_pts;
                    PRINT_VAL("ReScaled VID Dts ", outpkt.dts)
                    PRINT_MSG("=======================================")
                }

                outpkt.data = pkt.data;
                outpkt.size = pkt.size;
                outpkt.stream_index = pkt.stream_index;
                outpkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                last_vid_pts = vid_pts;
                if(av_interleaved_write_frame(m_outformat, &outpkt) < 0)
                {
                    PRINT_MSG("Failed Video Write ")
                }
                else
                {
                    m_out_vid_strm->codec->frame_number++;
                }
                av_free_packet(&outpkt);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
            }
            else if(pkt.stream_index == m_in_aud_strm_idx)
            {
                PRINT_VAL("ACTUAL AUD Pkt PTS ", av_rescale_q(pkt.pts, m_in_aud_strm->time_base, m_in_aud_strm->codec->time_base))
                PRINT_VAL("ACTUAL AUD Pkt DTS ", av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, m_in_aud_strm->time_base, m_in_aud_strm->codec->time_base))
                //num_aud_pkt++;
                av_init_packet(&outpkt);
                if(pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                {
                    outpkt.pts = aud_pts;
                    PRINT_VAL("ReScaled AUD PTS ", outpkt.pts)
                }
                else
                {
                    outpkt.pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
                }

                if(pkt.dts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                {
                    outpkt.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    outpkt.dts = aud_pts;
                    PRINT_VAL("ReScaled AUD DTS ", outpkt.dts)
                    PRINT_MSG("====================================")
                    if( outpkt.pts >= outpkt.dts)
                    {
                        outpkt.dts = outpkt.pts;
                    }
                    if(outpkt.dts == aud_dts)
                    {
                        outpkt.dts++;
                    }
                    if(outpkt.pts < outpkt.dts)
                    {
                        outpkt.pts = outpkt.dts;
                        aud_pts = outpkt.pts;
                    }
                }

                outpkt.data = pkt.data;
                outpkt.size = pkt.size;
                outpkt.stream_index = pkt.stream_index;
                outpkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                vid_pts = aud_pts;
                aud_pts++;
                if(av_interleaved_write_frame(m_outformat, &outpkt) < 0)
                {
                    PRINT_MSG("Faile Audio Write ")
                }
                else
                {
                    m_out_aud_strm->codec->frame_number++;
                }
                av_free_packet(&outpkt);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
        else
        {
            PRINT_MSG("Got Unknown Pkt ")
            //num_unkwn_pkt++;
        }
        //num_total_pkt++;
    }

    av_write_trailer(m_outformat);
    av_free_packet(&outpkt);
    av_free_packet(&pkt);
    return 0;    
 }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I do set pts, just haven't put it here.Yeah, what I need is to add audio to the video I am encoding.The audio comes from aac media file.Thanks a lot for this example, I will check it out as till now anything I tried didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't I open audio and video codecs via avcodec_open2() before the encoding as it is shown in FFMPEG examples?

Comment: Yes for encoding you would need to call avcodec_open2() before. In my case I was just doing stream copy so I didn't use it. But you would need to do.

Comment: I am getting this error: Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0 .I think it is related to the difference of pkt initialization...Do I have to call "av_read_frame" If I encode new video frame from image on each frame?Because calling avcodec_encode_video2() I also init  pkt ,then I am not sure which packet to use ...

Comment: You will need to call av_read_frame only when you are getting frame from file. If you are creating video from image then you don't need to call it. The error which you are getting is related to improper dts. How you are setting your pts?. If you are incrementing pts monotonically . Just try pkt.dts = pkt.pts before writing frame.

Comment: Then how do I check pkt.stream_index ?

Comment: If you are reading audio frame from file then you will need to av_read_frame(). Now you can check for which frame is audio or which frame is video by matching with stream index of input file. So in the init you will also need to open your input file and store the index of audio/video stream. Then you can compare the index of read packet with the stored one to separate audio and video frame.

Comment: Can I calc and set pts the same way as in this demo? http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html  Currently I am still gettting that error.

Comment: You can try doing it as done it demo. However if it doesn't work then you will need to set on you own.

Comment: Sorry for nagging you but what can be the problem if both streams pts are 0.0 always..?

Comment: Actually if you have just one stream then what I have seen the encoding works even if you do not set pts/dts yourself. However when dealing multiple streams you will have to set them properly and they will be used by decoder sync the two streams when playback is on. You can use a counter for each streams and use it to set pts/dts when you write using av_write_interleaved. Also you would need to properly rescale them based on your stream time base and codec time base.

Comment: Do you mean that in one file you have 3 streams? I thought you have input images to encode in video and input from file (audio in). Use these two you are trying to mux into single .mp4 file with 1 audio and 1 video stream. So your output mp4 file will have 1 audio and 1 video stream. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually my intention is to have 1 audio in and one video (from image frames) but I did as in your setup and you also have 2 audio streams..

Comment: In my setup too I have 1 audio and 1 video stream in output. Here is what I'm doing. I'm first opening input file to get audio and video stream index. This will be required to separate audio and video frame when I'm reading frame from input file. Once I have input stream index. I'm then opening output file and adding 1 audio and 1 video stream to it. So in output I have just 1 audio and 1 video stream. Then I'm writing frames in loop

Comment: So that means I can use the same audio stream for reading and writing audio frame?

Comment: No, input and output stream will be different. Basic input stream will come from your input file from which you wish to copy audio. And output stream is the one which you have created using avformat_new_stream() for your output file. They are different.

Comment: I managed to encode only a single video frame then it never enters again the video encode part but keeps on encoding audio only.Probably pts thing.Can I somehow contact you in other way so you can take a look at my encode loop part?Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have also started with ffmpeg recently so I'm not sure how much I can help it. Still you can share your code with me I can look into it. praks411@gmail.com

Comment: Dear @praks411, Could you please answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160039/how-to-packet-encoded-aac-data-to-flv-file-with-ffmpeg-api

Thanks.

Comment: @praks411
Dear praks411, Could you please have a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517703/mix-video-and-audio-to-mp4-file-with-ffmpeg-but-audio-doest-keep-step-with-vide

Comment: @praks411 Hello. I am running this code, the sound wokr fine, but the video zooms through. Like it's only showing key frames or something. It's an avi file.

Comment: From what I remember you will have to properly set video stream time base, frame rate and duration just like done in example code and also use  av_interleaved_frame_write. I hope this helps

Comment: @praks411 : Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055979/mux-audio-and-video-ffmpeg-c , if u can please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You may use AVBlocks library ([example](http://wiki.avblocks.com/wiki/avblocks-programming/using-transcoder/working-containers/mux-audio-video-mp4/)). I used the example code to solve the same problem.

For correct work not only with .aac I made some changes in StreamType::* and StreamSubType::*