# How to packet encoded AAC data to flv file with ffmpeg API?

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, live-streaming, aac, streaming-flv-video

I have captured the Audio data from Android Microphone and encoded them by MediaCodec.

My question is:

**How to packet encoded AAC data to flv with ffmpeg ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to packet audio into flv :

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c copy out.flv
```

If you have a video track to go with :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.aac -c copy out.flv
```